# Another way to use $this and prev etc to navigate a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, append

working on an ajax commenting system and so far everything is good.

Now im putting the finishing touches in and come across an issue.

If there is a no comments, there is a div placed inside the comments div which simply says "This blog has no comments"

When posting a comment, i am trying to remove this div. The issue however is that the no comments div is removed, but the comment is not appended. I have put this down to the fact im using .prev() and .closest() and im removing something its looking for? I may be wrong...

So here is what the structure would look like if there was no comments:

```
<div class="commentson">
    <div class="commentsholder"> 
        <div class='nocomments'>This update has no comments. Why not add one?</div>
    </div>
<form class="addcomment" action="process/addcomment.php" method="post">
    <div class="commentbutton">
    <input type="text" maxlength="250" name="addpostcomment" class="addpostcomment" placeholder="Add Comment... (max 60 characters)" />
    <input type="submit" id="addcommentbutton" class="addcommentbutton" value="Post" disabled/>
    </div>
    <span class="countdownCommentLength"></span>
</form>
```

Here is what the ajax success looks like:

```
$this = $(this);

if (response.commentSuccess === true) {
    $this.closest('.addcomment').prev().append("APPENDED COMMENT");
    $targetForm.find('.addpostcomment').val('');
    $(".nocomments").remove();
    $(".commentsholder").scrollTop($(".commentsholder")[0].scrollHeight);
}
```

This actually works fine if i remove the .prev and using prepend like so:

```
  $this.closest('.addcomment').prepend("APPENDED COMMENT");
```

But it orders my comments incorrectly. If i remove the .prev and simply do .append then the comment gets appended under the form as you would expect.

Have tried lots of combos, but just cant find another way that works. As a note, there are multiple forms on each page like this.

Comment: Which object in your HTML is `$this`?  We can't follow your code without knowing that.  Is it the add comment button?

Comment: sorry always forget to add. Ill edit the question. The this is declared at the top of the form simply as $this = $(this)

Comment: So, then which object is `this`?  I want to know what HTML object that  is a reference to?

Comment: the form submit that is submitted :)

Comment: There must be something else going on that you aren't disclosing because when I build a mini version of your code/HTML in a jsFiddle and press the "Add" button, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/pbq2R/

Comment: Hmm, thanks for trying. I cant recreate the issue. Ill go back to the start and see if i can figure it out.